# How to add custom variable to jQuery sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am currently making a sortable table, and need to pass more than just the id to the serialized array.

Iv added all my code exept the post file, that dossent relly do anything else than var_dumping post.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"><br><br><br><br>
            <table class="display table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dt-responsive responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <th>Navn</th>
                <th>Order</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="sortable">
                <tr id="order_1" data-extravalue="45">
                    <td>value</t>
                </tr>
                <tr id="order_2" data-extravalue="56">
                    <td>value</t>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $('#sortable').sortable({
            update: function( event, ui ) {

                var order = $("#sortable").sortable('serialize');

                $.ajax({
                    data: order,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'post.php'
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly, you should close you `<td>` tags properly: `<td></td>`. Second, what other info are you trying to collect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but this might help you out. Since you're posting to PHP, you will need to use `json_decode()` upon `$_POST['json']`.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/a2e9626L/4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <table class="display table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dt-responsive responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <th>Navn</th>
          <th>Order</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="sortable">
          <tr id="order_1" data-extravalue="45">
            <td>value</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="order_2" data-extravalue="56">
            <td>value</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $('#sortable').sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var order = $("#sortable").sortable('serialize');
      var data = [];
      $("#sortable tr").each(function(i, el) {
        data.push({
          order: $(el).attr("id"),
          value: $(el).data("extravalue")
        });
      });
      $.ajax({
        data: {
          json: JSON.stringify(data)
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'post.php'
        success: function(d) {
          console.log(d);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind exposing the parameters, you can always append them into the request URL.

In your case, like this:

```
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        update: function( event, ui ) {

            var order = $("#sortable").sortable('serialize');

            $.ajax({
                data: order,
                type: 'POST',
                url: "post.php?extra_param=value,another_extra_param=another_value"
            });
        }
    });
```

I have encountered this blocker today, but in Rails, and this is how I solved it.